# Animated div show/hide (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, animation

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('#small-form').animate({
        width: ['toggle', 'swing'],
        height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
        opacity: 'toggle'
    }, 5000, 'linear');
    $('#big-form').animate({
        width: ['toggle', 'swing'],
        height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
        opacity: 'toggle'
    }, 5000, 'linear');
});
```

... this HIDEs both the elements, I want to hide small and show the big form.

Thanks!

Comment: is `#big-form` already hidden ?

Comment: Wrapper is 100px with overflow:hidden, small-form is 100px so big-form is hidden even without display:none

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with you codes, it depends. if both forms are visible, then both are shown. Toggle means do the opposite, - if it's hidden, show it - if its height is greater than 0, make it 0.

suggestions:

1.) your code can be simplified to.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('#small-form, #big-form').animate({
        width: ['toggle', 'swing'],
        height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
        opacity: 'toggle'
    }, 5000, 'linear');
});
```

2.) try hiding one of it first. Something like `$('#small-form').hide()`

Comment: Its works great. Previously I was doing it with css height and then expanding div to auto height but this small snippet is very short and did all magic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('.button').click(function() {
$('#small-form').animate({
    width: ['toggle', 'swing'],
    height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
    opacity: 'toggle'
}, 5000, 'linear',
complete: $('#big-form').animate({
    width: ['toggle', 'swing'],
    height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
    opacity: 'toggle'
}, 5000, 'linear');
});
```

use complete: A function to call once the animation is complete.
OR      step: A function to be called after each step of the animation.